# querySelectorAll's click button issue

Tags: selectors-api

Anyone know why the below code is not working? suppose the website will get back something if i click the arrow button, any code i typed wrong in `querySelectorAll`?  many thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <style>
        .buttons {
            font-size: 48px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dance Time</h1>    
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
    <script>
        let arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons .fas')
        for (const arrow of arrows) {
            arrow.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if (arrow.classList.contains('fa-arrow-up')) {  
            console.log('arrow clicked')
                }
        })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no code in that HTML to send anything to the server/website. If you open the browser console, it might show some messages. Perhaps the event listener would log 'arrow clicked' if you click on the arrow-up icon.

Comment: yes, suppose the would log 'arrow clicked' but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

you had a wrong div placed after the buttons div there ,,,
that was probably the reason ... check again and let me know if sth goes wrong

```js
        let arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons .fas')
        for (const arrow of arrows) {
            arrow.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if (arrow.classList.contains('fa-arrow-up')) {  
            console.log('arrow clicked')
                }
        })
        }
```

```css
  .buttons {
            font-size: 48px;
        }
```

```html
    <h1>Dance Time</h1>    
    <div class="buttons">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-up">first</i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-down">second</i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left">third</i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right">fourth</i>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for prompt suggesting, Do you mean here is wrong " let arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons .fas')"  ?

Comment: no .. the closing div after <div class="buttons"> is wrong ..

Comment: oh!!!!!!!! i spent almost 5hour to find the reason.. thank you man!